# Can't compile metapost files

Tags: luatex, compiling, texstudio, metapost

I have been searching for a solution to this and I haven't found one. I have a tex file that uses metapost that compiles on one system but not on the other.

On the system that fails the log says:

```
Module luamplib Warning: This is MetaPost, Version 2.000
(luamplib)               
(luamplib)               
(luamplib)               
(luamplib)               ! I can't open file `plain.mp'.
(luamplib)               <*>     input plain.mp
(luamplib)                                      ;
(luamplib)               Please type another input file name
(luamplib)               ! Emergency stop.
(luamplib)               <*>     input plain.mp
(luamplib)                                      ;
(luamplib)               *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
(luamplib)               
(luamplib)               
(luamplib)               on input line 13
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: 
Module luamplib Error: see above messages on input line 13
```

But I am not including that mp file at all, I am including:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=4cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibnumbersystem{double}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{mplibcode}
input metapost/lattice.mp;

\end{mplibcode}
\par}
\end{document}
```

And the file `metapost/lattice.mp` exists under the current relative path (checked). I am compiling with lualatex on TexStudio.

OS is Ubuntu. I tried updating packages and redownloading all tex related packages I remember using but alas problem is the same.
[image]

Comment: `plain.mp` is necessary for `luamplib`. Try directly on your
console `lualatex filename.tex`. If it succeeds, the problem
may be a setting of `TeXStudio`. If it fails, your configuration
is broken. Can `kpsewhich plain.mp` find the file `plain.mp`?

Comment: Given the path in the error message above, you would expect to find `plain.mp` in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/metapost/base/` -- if you can't find it, then I guess that you might need to install [texlive-metapost](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/texlive-metapost/filelist), which is the package that provides it.

Comment: It has been months but, installing the package was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answering this as per comments)

Given the path in the error message above, you would expect to find `plain.mp` in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/metapost/base/` -- since you can't find it, then apparently you need to install [texlive-metapost](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/texlive-metapost/filelist), which is the package that provides it.